# MySql. DB owner and car

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in my DB:
[owner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1LXM.png)
[car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW5ti.png)

I have to extract the owners that haven't a car and live in IT, we are talking about "Arthur".

```
SELECT * FROM owner, car WHERE city = 'IT' and owner.idOwner != car.idOwnerFK
```

city is working but not like the second part.
How can i solve my problem? Thanks

Comment: Who is Arthur??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT  * FROM owner WHERE city = 'IT' and idOwner not in (select  idOwnerFK from car)
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to do a left join on car from owner. Something like this should work:

```
select * from owner o
left join car c on o.idOwner = c.idOwnerFK
where o.city = 'IT' and c.idcar is null
```

Comment: Was about to post exactly this. In action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33282/2